# Use same slug base for Custom Post Type posts, and multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have done a lot of digging the past few days, and can come close, but not exactly what I need.
I'm trying to alter a custom taxonomy/CPT permalink structure to all use the same slug base: /resources/.

```
CPT: 'resources'

TAX1, non-hierarchical: 'type'

TAX2, hierarchical: 'section'
```

I need the structure to look like this:

**/resources/** = post type archive **WORKS**
**/resources/$post-name** = all Resources posts **DOESN'T WORK - 404**
**/resources/$type-term/** = archive **DOESN'T WORK - 404** 
**/resources/$type-term/page/1** = pagination for type-term archive **DOESN'T WORK**
**/resources/$section-term-parent/** = archive **WORKS**
**/resources/$section-term-parent/$section-term-child/** = archive  **WORKS**
**/resources/$section-term-parent/$section-term-child/page/2** = pagination for section-child-term archive **WORKS**

I need to remove the taxonomy names from both taxonomies, and use only the term name. Both taxonomies need to have /resources/ before them in the URL. The single posts need /resources/ before the post slug. It needs to be set at the WP level and not .htaccess because we have a load balancer directing all non-resources traffic to another system. If it's not in /resources/ it will never hit WP.

I can only get one taxonomy at a time to use the link structure, but not both. If I change the order in which I register them - Section before Type, then Type works and Section doesn't.

The only way the single post url works is if I change the slug in the CPT definition to something other than resources.

Registering content types:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_type_taxonomy', 1 );
function create_type_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                      => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name', 'mysite' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'              => true,
        'labels'                    => $labels,
        'show_ui'                   => true,
        'show_admin_column'         => true,
        'update_count_callback'     => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'                 => true,
        'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => true ),
        'show_in_rest'              => true,
        'rest_base'                 => 'type',
        'rest_controller_class'     => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller',
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'resources', $args );
}


add_action( 'init', 'create_resources_cpt' );
function create_resources_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Resources', 'Post type general name', 'mysite' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 15,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
           'supports'        => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'type', 'section' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'resources', $args );
}



function create_section_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Sections', 'taxonomy general name', 'mysite' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => false ),
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rest_base'             => 'section',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller',
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'section', array( 'resources' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_section_taxonomy', 1 );
```

Comment: One problem is that WordPress cannot tell the difference between a `$post-name` and a `$type-term` since they're on the same level. If you added some kind of static separator between one of the two ( or both) so that it's a unique path ( ex. `type/$type-term` ) I think it would work.

Comment: Getting anywhere? Damn this is a pia,

Comment: @Christina yes! The pagination was a separate issue I solved with pre_get_posts() and get_query_var(), because I had altered the global ppp for some taxonomies. I will upload my solution for the permalinks structure separately. There are *a lot* of moving parts.

Comment: any solution to this? I got the same problem.

Comment: @user1266231 This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/233299)

Comment: I've converted the answer to a comment, do not derail questions by posting comments as solutions. You run the risk of being flagged as a spambot